# Mongodb incremental backups

Tags: bash, mongodb, backup

I was given the task to setup incremental backups for mongodb replicaset, as start point of course I googled about it and could not find anything on mongodb docs, I did find however this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974071/want-to-do-an-incremental-backup-for-mongodb-journaling-oplog) which encouraged to develop my own solution as didn't find Tayra very active.

I read about oplog and realized it was very easy to develop something to replay the log, but it turns out that I didn't have to as `mongorestore` does that for me.

Now I have a working solution with bash scripts and it was  quite easy, that's the reason I am asking here if there is any flaw in my logic, or maybe something that will bite me in the future.

Below how I implemented that:

**Full backup procedure:**

1. lock writes on a secondary member `db.fsyncLock()`
2. Take snapshot
3. Record last position from oplog

`db.oplog.rs.find().sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1).next().ts`

4. Unlock writes `db.fsyncUnlock()`

**Incremental backup procedure:**

1. lock writes on a secondary member
2. Dump oplog from the recorded oplog position on full (or latest incremental ) backup:
   `mongodump --host <secondary> -d local -c oplog.rs -o /mnt/mongo-test_backup/1 --query '{ "ts" : { $gt :  Timestamp(1437725201, 50) } }'`
3. Record latest oplog position (same way as for full backups)
4. Unlock writes

**Full backup restore procedure:**

1. stop all instances of mongod
2. copy snapshot to data dir of the box which will be the primary, but make sure to exclude all `local*` and `mongod.lock`  this restore technique is called [reconfigure by breaking mirror](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/#replica-set-reconfigure-by-replacing)
3. Start primary
4. reconfigure replicaset
5. start secondaries without any data, let them perform initial sync. Or copy the data from the new primary with fresh `local` database

**Restore incremental backup:**

When we created incremental backup it stored it like this:

```
/mnt/mongo-test_backup/1/local/oplog.rs.bson
/mnt/mongo-test_backup/1/local/oplog.rs.metadata.json
```

We're instered on oplog.rs.bson but we will have to rename it, so here are the steps:

1. change directory to the backup: `cd /mnt/mongo-test_backup/1/local`
2. delete the json file `rm *.json`
3. rename the bson file `mv oplog.rs.bson oplog.bson`
4. restore it :
   `mongorestore -h <primary> --port <port> --oplogReplay /mnt/mongo-test_backup/1/local`

I have it all scripted, I may commit it on github later.

Question is if there is any flaw in the logic. I am bit suspicious as the procedure is quite straight forward and still I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) is the place to discuss backup and restore procedures.