# Taking snapshots of the mongodb opslog?

Tags: mongodb

Does mongodb support generating opslog snapshots?  For example suppose I have a delayed replicate set that is delayed by 24 hours.  Twelve hours into the next next day someone accidentally deletes all data.  We can go back to the 24 delayed replicate set and get a restore, but would also like to apply the ops that contains entries almost up to the point where the failure happened.  Does mongodb support the generation of opslog snapshots / versioned opslogs?  For example a new version of the opslog for every 50 new writes?

There is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974071/want-to-do-an-incremental-backup-for-mongodb-journaling-oplog) out there.  What I'm asking is whether it's possible to generate snapshots of the opslog such that we can restore mongodb to a particular point in time given a certain time starting point.  For example mongodb cloud atlas claims that it can do this, so I was wondering whether there is also a process that can be implemented by db adminstrators that does the same thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to do an incremental backup for mongodb. Journaling? Oplog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974071/want-to-do-an-incremental-backup-for-mongodb-journaling-oplog)